Sequelize-typescript query runs infinite when using $get with eager loading
I have tried using eager loading in combination with the $get method on a sequelize object:
await user?.$get("following", {
    order: [["name", "ASC"]],
    limit: USERS_PER_PAGE,
    offset: (page - 1) * USERS_PER_PAGE,
    where,
    include: Gym
}

The query worked fine, until I added the include parameter. It returns an Array of users that have a 1:1 relation to the Gym model through a foreign key in the Gym model. Including the Gym works fine with the findOne and findMany method.
This approach leads to the Promise neither resolving nor rejecting with an error.
Am I missing something/doing somethig wrong or is this an error in sequelize-typescript?

There are couple of possible causes to this issue, since the query keeps running and the promise is not getting resolved or rejected it's probably a circular dependency issue, basically when the query runner fetches the users and join the gym object it will get the gym with it's users , then it will try to fetch the users inside the gym it will find a gym property in each one ....etc .  so it keeps running like:  user -> gym -> user -> gym , and it's a common issue with eager loading and orms.
The reason why the issue disappears when using findAll is the differences on the internal orm implementations between $get and findAll methods which maybe built in a way to avoid circular dependency
To solve this try including only the properties that you need from the gym model in the query , it will give you a clue whether it's a circular dependency issue or not :
await user?.$get("following", {
    order: [["name", "ASC"]],
    limit: USERS_PER_PAGE,
    offset: (page - 1) * USERS_PER_PAGE,
    where,
    include: {model: Gym, attributes: ['id', 'other_gym_attributes']}
}


This sadly didn't fix the issue. I tried including only the id attribute but still the promise didn't resolve or reject

I have found a workaround by accessing the table of the n:M relation and then including user and from user gym. But I think there should be a better way....

ok , since it may not be a circular dependency issue, it will be helpful if you provide model definition for user, gym to check how relations are set .
